# Регулярное выражение для BOOL атрибутов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярку для `bool` атрибута в разных HTML тегах.Регулярка может как и искать,так и заменять на более валидный вариант.Как пример в фрейме ютуба есть вещь - `allowfullscreen` без каких либо параметров.Можно заменить на `allowfullscreen=''` или удалить.У самого что-то не получается.

Comment: Правильно я понимаю что надо сделать замену `<tag boolattribute attr="2">` на <tag attr="2"> или <tag boolattribute="" attr="2">` где boolattribute может быть любой строкой?

Comment: @newman Правильно ...

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, вашу задачу не решить регулярными выражениями.

Однако это не значит, что ее вообще нельзя решить.
Удалить пустые атрибуты можно с помощью [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) и [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domxpath.php). Вот так:

Пример на [**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/BSmqpA)

```
$string = "<p class=x11111111111111111 atthhh test>Bla bla.</p>";

$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// Все элементы. В выборку попадут только валидные теги. Увы.
$elements = $xpath->query('//*');

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $attributes = $element->attributes;
    $i = 0;
    $total = $attributes->length;
    while ($i <= $total) {
        // Проверяем, атрибут ли нам попался
        if($attributes->item($i) instanceof DOMAttr) {
            // Проверяем, пустой ли атрибут
            if (empty($attributes->item($i)->value)) {
                // Удаляем атрибут
                $element->removeAttributeNode($attributes->item($i));
                // После удаления атрибута, нужно отмотать счетчик назад
                $i--;
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
} 
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Результат:

```
<p class="x11111111111111111">Bla bla.</p>
```

---

**Обратите внимание на флаги** `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` **и** `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD`.

Без них вывод был бы таким

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p class="x11111111111111111">Bla bla.</p></body></html>
```

Начиная с версии PHP 5.4 и Libxml 2.6 в методе [`loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtml.php) появился второй параметр `$option`, который поясняет Libxml, как следует парсить HTML

> LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED (integer)
>   Устанавливает флаг `HTML_PARSE_NOIMPLIED`, который отключает автоматическое добавление недостающих html/body... элементов.

> LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD (integer)
>   Устанавливает флаг `HTML_PARSE_NODEFDTD`, который предотвращает добавление стандартного doctype, если он не был найден.

Все предопределенные константы можно посмотреть в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/libxml.constants.php).

### Внимание

Скрипт отработает только на валидной разметке.

Хотя в документации указано, что требуется Libxml версии 2.6, однако `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` доступен только с версии 2.7.8, а `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` с версии 2.7.7